# Flexbox in Safari: Grow and shrink

Tags: css, safari, flexbox

I am trying to make a cross-browser flexbox layout, to display cards positioned alongside one another. They should be left- or right-aligned (determined by "left" and "right" classes) when there is enough space for all cards, but shrink when there isn't. When shrinking, mouseover a card would make it shrink less, so that more of it can be viewed.

So much talk about this, [live demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/GdKvG/) if you prefer.

CSS:

```
img{
   width:90px;
    position: absolute;
}

.cards{
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-justify-content: flex-start;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
.cards.right{
    float: right;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row-reverse;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
    -ms-flex-direction: row-reverse;
    -ms-justify-content: flex-end;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.cards div{
    position:relative;
    -webkit-flex: 0 2 90px;
    -ms-flex: 0 2 90px;
    flex: 0 2 90px;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0 2 90px;
    transition: flex-shrink .3s;
    transition: flex-shrink .3s, -webkit-flex .3s;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-flex .3s;
}
.cards.left div:last-child, .cards.right div:first-child{
    -webkit-flex: 0 0 90px;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 90px;
    flex: 0 0 90px;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0 0 90px;
}
.cards.left div:not(:last-child):hover, .cards.right div:hover+div{
    -webkit-flex: 0 1 90px;
    -ms-flex: 0 1 90px;
    flex: 0 1 90px;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0 1 90px;
}
```

So far I have successfully created the desired layout in lastest versions of IE, FF, Chorme and Opera.
However, I am running into problems with Safari. They layout depends on being able to specify different flexibilities for grow and shrink, but as far as I can tell, Safari does not support this.

Any help on growing and shrinking flexboxes in Safari is appreciated. I don't want to fallback to my old table-based layout as it tends to break in IE and FF.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the only Safari I have access to is version 5 for Windows, I can't confirm how this works in anything newer than that.

There's nothing you can do about the lack of support for flex-shrink and flex-grow as independent values.  My advice would be to not use flex-shrink for this purpose but to use padding instead.  You get almost the same effect in this particular instance, and it works in Safari 5:

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/oHzgr

```
img {
  width: 90px;
  position: absolute;
}

.cards {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -webkit-flexbox;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: start;
  -moz-box-pack: start;
  -webkit-flex-pack: start;
  -ms-flex-pack: start;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.cards.right {
  float: right;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: reverse;
  -moz-box-direction: reverse;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row-reverse;
  -ms-flex-direction: row-reverse;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  -webkit-box-pack: end;
  -moz-box-pack: end;
  -webkit-flex-pack: end;
  -ms-flex-pack: end;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.cards div {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 90px;
  -webkit-box-flex: 2;
  -moz-box-flex: 2;
  -webkit-flex: 0 2 90px;
  -ms-flex: 0 2 90px;
  flex: 0 2 90px;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-flex .3s;
  transition: flex-shrink .3s;
  transition: flex-shrink .3s, -webkit-flex .3s;
}

.cards.left div:last-child, .cards.right div:first-child {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -moz-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 90px;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 90px;
  flex: 0 0 90px;
}

.cards.left div:not(:last-child):hover, .cards.right div:hover + div {
  padding-right: 5%;
}
```

You'll need to change the transition to padding, of course, but otherwise it looks like it works.

Comment: Would be great if I can target Safari specifically, but it works in all browsers anyway.

Comment: Cheers man! I took this (.cards) and put it in .flex, then I can just @extend .flex throughout my sass (scss)! Works like a charm :)